# No architectures to compile for Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running xcode 6.1

I am upgrading a project that was originally targeted to 4.3 to latest iOS and SDKs. When I run against simulator, it compiles fine against all simulators less than iPhone 5S, it works on iPhone4,4S, iphone5 both (7 & 8). However When I select devices iPhone 5S and iPhone 6, I get the error: No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386).

Settings:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Your valid architectures should read `armvv7, armv7s, arm64`
Otherwise you do not allow (at least) arm64. 
You also do not need to make a difference between debug & release when that is the same

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did try adding what you mentioned to valid archs, but still got the error.

Comment: did you add that to "Valid Architectures"? Or to "Architectures"? Because the latter should not require the full list ..
Also I had an issue with supported architectures after installing Xcode 6.1 - I have been able to resolve it by restarting my Mac. Restarting only Xcode was not enough ...

Comment: I added to valid archs, attached image in original question. Note I also added i386 to see if it made a difference but it didn't. What could be different going from iphone5 to iphone5S knowing that iOS7 and iOS8 work fine with iPhone5?

Comment: I suspect your deployment target is quite old.  In order to support 64bit, it needs to be at least 6.0.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do the following:

1. Delete local modifications to valid architectures such that it returns to default values.
2. Delete local modifications to architectures such that it returns to default values.
3. Make sure that your deployment target is at least 6.0.  Setting it to a version older than 6.0 will not allow you to support 64bit.

The default architecture values will just show arm archs.  You don't need to include i386 and x86_64.  Xcode takes care of translating your arm archs to appropriate intel archs when building for the sim.  For example, if you have armv6, armv7, or armv7s in valid archs or archs, that will be internally translated to i386 when building for the sim.

Comment: I did try the above, still same error. Target is set to latest (8.1), and it works with iphone4 &5, I still get the error when selecting iphone5S and iphone6

Comment: If that's true, then your Valid architectures and architectures are still not set correctly.  Make sure you're not overriding the default value.  Show an updated screenshot.

Comment: Attached images in original question. Please let me know if I misunderstood. Thanks again for helping with something that's driving me totally insane.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that "Valid Architectures" is incorrectly set (note that the text is bold), and the values aren't shown because the expand triangle is closed.  Click on it and hit delete.

Comment: Also, if you want to test 32bit on 64bit devices, you will want to set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No"

Comment: Right now, valid archs don't have any value in it. Should it have values? If I click (+) for Debug and Release, it pops the dialog box so I can specify, but I left it blank.

Comment: Yes, you left it *blank* which is not the same as setting it to *default*.  Click on it and then press delete in order to reset it to default value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65988/discussion-between-user1529412-and-jeremy-huddleston-sequoia).

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually remove overwritten VALID_ARCH settings from the project file to get it to build simulator. For whatever reason if you overwrite them at target level it doesn't work (for me at least) and you can't remove them in Xcode as it replaces them with empty instead of inheriting them from project settings.